# Unable to deploy react application to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

so I just finished building the beta version of my e-commerce application and decided to deploy to heroku from my github repository.
The first issue I ran into was not npm run build (which I did then pushed it to github) then redeployed.
Next issue was my build failed because I didn't specify the version of node. (SO i want into the package.json and typed in...)

"engines": {
"node": "16.14.2"
},
Again, redeployed I got through the build and I thought all was well. BUT I get an application error  (fun) and so I go into heroku logs to see what I did wrong. Problem is I actually don't know what i did wrong. This is what the log says

[image: Heroku Log for application deployment]

[image: Package.json]

Comment: it's obviously a memory problem, but from the screenshots it's hard to say what the cause of the problem is. Check out this article, it gives you some advice on how to deal with out-of-memory-problems on heroku: https://bismobaruno.medium.com/fixing-memory-heap-reactjs-on-heroku-16910e33e342

Comment: thanks ! @SteffenFrank I'll check on that now !